# form->bind($request) during ajax call outputs an array

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

### I am posting a form with Ajax.

**I have a surprising response when binding a form within an Ajax call:**

```
public function newCartAjaxAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->container->get('new_cart_form.factory')->create();
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('new_cart_form.handler');

    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod())
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $formHandler->processValidForm($form);

            $response = new Response();
            $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
            $response->setContent(json_encode('hello'));
            return $response;
        }
        //...
    }

    //....
}
```

**Using firebug, I surprisingly obtain 3 outputs in the ajax Response:**

```
array(2) {[0]=>int(3)[1]=>int(5)}    //unexpected response

int(3)                               //unexpected response

"hello"                              //The only response needed
```

After debugging, I figured out that output 1 and 2 are from `$form->bind($request);`

Does anyone know why that is? I am very surprised to obtain a response from the form binding step as the only response that I am supposed to send is $response...

**Have I done something wrong?**

Comment: Please, paste place where you put `console.log()` and full contents of output?

Comment: First, re install your vendor, and then, make sure you've not hooked anything with your form (event listeners...)

Comment: @AdrienBrault, this is it! well done. Event listeners were the problem. I had a stupid var_dump for debug that I forgot to remove. This led to an html reponse from ajax. Damn, you're good! please post a reply so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that these outputs were caused by code you've written.

First, make sure that your vendors are clean by reinstalling them.
Then, it could also be a form event listener/subscriber that you've written, so have also a look in this way.